# Problem making a 1D Nester using Google OR Tools

Tags: python, or-tools

First of all, I apologize for bothering all of you, but I have no formal training in programming and I have run out of ideas on how to solve this.

I'm trying to create a 1D Nester using the Google OR Tools. This Nester will create a list of cutting plans from a list of cuts, thus making a material list for a given project.

The code itself is a modified version of the "Bin Packing Problem" from https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/bin_packing.

```
from ortools.linear_solver 
import pywraplp

def generate_cutting_plan(tube_list, material_lenght):
    data = {}
    weights = []

    #append each length with a kerf of 5mm
    for s in tube_list:
        weights.append(int(s)+5)

    data['weights'] = weights
    data['items'] = list(range(len(weights)))
    data['bins'] = data['items']
    data['bin_capacity'] = int(material_lenght)

    print("Data plan created")

    # Create the mip solver with the SCIP backend.
    solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')

    print("Solver updated")

    # Variables
    # x[i, j] = 1 if item i is packed in bin j.
    x = {}
    for i in data['items']:
        for j in data['bins']:
            x[(i, j)] = solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'x_%i_%i' % (i, j))

    # y[j] = 1 if bin j is used.
    y = {}
    for j in data['bins']:
        y[j] = solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'y[%i]' % j)

    # Constraints
    # Each item must be in exactly one bin.
    for i in data['items']:
        solver.Add(sum(x[i, j] for j in data['bins']) == 1)

    # The amount packed in each bin cannot exceed its capacity.
    for j in data['bins']:
        solver.Add(
            sum(x[(i, j)] * data['weights'][i] for i in data['items']) <= y[j] *
            data['bin_capacity'])

    print("Initiating optimization...")

    # Objective: minimize the number of bins used.
    solver.Minimize(solver.Sum([y[j] for j in data['bins']]))

    print("Solving...")

    status = solver.Solve()

    print("Optimization complete")

    plans = []

    if status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL:
        num_bins = 0.
        plans = []
        for j in data['bins']:
            if y[j].solution_value() == 1:
                bin_items = []
                bin_weight = 0
                tv_array = []
                for i in data['items']:
                    if x[i, j].solution_value() > 0:
                        bin_items.append(i)
                        bin_weight += data['weights'][i]
                        tv_array.append(int(data['weights'][i])-5)

                if bin_weight > 0:
                    num_bins += 1

                plans.append(tv_array)

        print(plans)
    else:
        print('The problem does not have an optimal solution.')

    print("Returning rezults...")

    return plans

test_cut_list = [1501, 1501, 1501, 2882, 2882, 2882, 1602, 1602, 1602, 1602, 1602, 2553, 2553, 2553, 1476, 2255, 2255, 2255, 2255]

print(generate_cutting_plan(test_cut_list, 6000))
```

The problem is that the code stops at the solver (meaning that it prints "Solving..." and then nothing). This happens at some specific cut_lists. For example, for the cut_list in the above code, the code stops, but if I change the value "1476" in the cut_list array to "1475" it works.

The problem is not the length of the array itself, since I have tried longer arrays but with smaller values.

If anyone could enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong I would be grateful.

Comment: First, you should enable solver logs. solver.EnableOutput().

Comment: I have enabled it and the output is interesting, that is, if I interpret it correctly. It seems to me it runs iterations to find the best possible solution through combinations??? Either way, at time 2219s it had run LP iter = 11289k and with increasing memory usage (1272M at that time). Am I actually having a memory problem?